# Python spaces around "and" but not around "+"

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

Why are preceding spaces optional before "keyword operators"? For example, the following code is valid `1+1`, even with no spaces around `+`, however it is clear what it means, and several programmers code with no spaces between their operators. However `1and1` is not valid, **but** `1and 1` **is** valid.

Python usually "guides" the user to format mostly clean code, however, this allows the writing of some unfortunate code, such as `1.2e3jor 3`. That evaluates to `1200j`, where ``j` is the Python imaginary number literal. I'm curious as to why this is allowed, and why there hasn't been a PEP to disallow this. Surely there aren't a huge number of programs that depend on this behavior.

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Explain yourself better, show your code.

Comment: why would you need that syntax? are you trying to remove whitespaces from your code?

Comment: No. I've used python for a long time, and most things are really clear and force good formatting, but this is a counterexample to that belief.

Comment: This is a case of a good question asked the wrong way.

Comment: I've edited the question with possibly a more proper format.

Comment: @downvoter please explain if you still think the downvote is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Because the language and compiler was created that way. Also having "and" with variables without spaces can be confused with a variable. You can't have "+" and other operators in variable names, so this confusion never occurs.

Comment: Okay but is there any reason to allow `1and 2` to be a valid expression?

Comment: I see. Thank you. So `1jand 2` is valid only because there is no operator `jand`? Even more extreme, `1.1e1jor 1` is also valid.

Comment: You tested 1jand 2 is valid? How is 1j and valid?

Comment: Yes. `1j` is the imaginary literal in Python.